# Show that for all $x\in(0,1)$, $(1.5-x)(2-x)^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}-(x^2-3x+2)^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Show that for all $x\in(0,1)$

\begin{equation}
(1.5-x)(2-x)^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}-(x^2-3x+2)^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}>0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: $x^2 - 3x + 2 = (x-1)(x-2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that claim is incorrect.
Let $\frac{1}{\epsilon} = m \gt 0$.
$$(1.5-x)(2-x)^m \gt (x^2-3x+2)^m \iff(1.5-x)(2-x)^m \gt (2-x)^m (1-x)^m \\ \iff 1.5-x \gt (1-x)^m \\ \iff x+(1-x)^m \lt 1.5$$

But for $m\approx 0$ and near $x=1$, $$x+(1-x)^m \approx 1+1=2$$